# Can't export 300dpi jpeg in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, jpg

I have an A4 size artboard with pixels as the units that I want to export as JPG at 300dpi. Whenever I try to export, it asks me to lower the resolution. At max, I can export at 150 dpi. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this problem, nor have I ever had Illustrator "ask me" to lower the resolution. Would you mind showing a screenshot of your export settings, and the warning dialog you mention? Thanks.

Comment: I've had problems before. Not sure this will help you, but I have found that Photoshop handles things better (especially better than InDesign) when it comes to raster images – so what I have done on several ocations is exporting a PDF with the right resolution (if any raster elements), opened the PDF in Photoshop and adjusting the size & resolution as needed before saving to desired file format.

Comment: What size is the image?

Comment: @joojaa - absolutely a possible source of the problem, because potentially if the image is too big for the jpeg fomat, it might throw an error, although A4 at 300ppi shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @BillyKerr user says he has designed as pixels as unit but export at 300ppi is the same as making the image 4 1/6 times larger since unit pixel is fixed in size. And thus more than 17 times the memory usage. So if one is not careful that can really blow illustrators pixel budget

Comment: @2Br why export as pdf the ai file is allready pdf and photoshop reads that

Comment: @joojaa – Good question. My only _guess_ is that my mind were locked in InDesign-way-of-thought mode. Of course you are right - that you could use the AI-file directly in Photoshop. BTW: The main reason we don't export JPEGs directly from InDesign is that the quality tends to be horrible for our use. Not sure if Illustrator have the same issues, but would _guess_ that you still would have more control in Photoshop.

Comment: @2rB not really. Problem is that adobe does antialiasing in a bit dubious way you can get better results through using nonadobe native functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that illustrator has a very strange approach when using pixels as units.

When you combine the two units "A4" and "Pixels" it automatically forces the artboard to 72PPI.

What you can do is re-assign cm or in as units.

Comment: Well, no not really like this. The size of a A4 is immutable in illustrator. Unless you calculated the number of pixels needed for a a4 yourself. We dont know what the OP is facing. Anyway a pixel is not a unit, if you trat a pixel as a unit you eventually end up with a erroneus thinking at some point. (Just because ots a suffix does not make it a unit)

Comment: A pixel is a unit of information.

Comment: its a quantity yes. Qantities are unitless

Comment: "Unit. an individual thing or person regarded as single and complete but which can also form an individual component of a larger or more complex whole." What you are probably meaning is that a pixel has no physical dimension. "Some units have no defined physical dimension"... Untill they do.

Comment: Well yes the scientific and technical language of Metronomy, physical scienes etc differ a bit from natural language.

Comment: The problem is that you can have several different things called pixels in illustrator. Because its not a metronomical unit. Just like the unit apple can mean things you eat or laptops. So you can get really heavily burned by the fact that your imported image is 120 pixels wide but illustrator rulers report it as 80 pixels wide for example. So a pixel has no fixed definition you can have several things called a pixel inside a illustrator document.

Comment: Agree. Technical aspects should be understood by designers :o)